# Can I Use MySQLi and PHP5 Syntax Within CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, kohana

Im starting a new web project, and I figured I'd try using a framework. I know CodeIgniter is coded in PHP4, but will I be able to use the MySQLi functions of MySQL, as well as PHP5 syntax (when it comes to OO especially) while coding with CodeIgniter? Should I use Kohana instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can use whatever features in the version of PHP that you are running. Codeigniter runs fine on PHP5.

Also, Codeigniter includes a database driver for mysqli which can be set in system/application/config/database.php as:

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysqli";
```