# is it possible to use mysqli prepare statement with codeigniter version 2.1.4?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am developing a website and i am always cautious about the security. Working with `mysql database` using the prepare statement is a good choice to protect against `sql injection`. I am new to `codeigniter` and right now i am on `2.1.4 version`. Which is the latest one. I could not get any information about the usage of `mysqli` extension with my framework. I would appreciate if someone helps me. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies for the extreme necroposting, but this is an important question because most people using CI < 4 often do not know that the "compile_binds" function actually doesn't do anything like bind_param. It's a lie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522350/can-i-use-mysqli-and-php5-syntax-within-codeigniter), you can install the driver to use MySQLi syntax:

> Codeigniter includes a database driver for mysqli which can be set in
>   system/application/config/database.php as:

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysqli";
```

However, there are some limitations. From the various sources I've read ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156421/how-can-i-use-prepared-statements-in-codeigniter), for example), doing multiple queries or prepared statements do not seem possible. You still get some benefits using the MySQLi syntax, but definitely not fully capitalizing on MySQLi's capabilities.